# Google Docs Add-On - Dealing with Images

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, google-docs, google-docs-api

I'm trying to create a Google Docs add-on in which someone:

- Selects an image
- Clicks a menu item
- A dialog is displayed, showing the image (on a canvas) with a couple tools
- Canvas is modified using tools
- Canvas data is saved and replaces the original image
- Meta data for the image is saved, so it can be re-edited from the original.

I know how to get the image selection (from the GS code) and trigger the menu item and dialog. I also know how to do all of my custom code things.

I need to know:

- How to get the original image URL (or extract it as a base64 string) that I can put in to a canvas
- Replace the image and save it in the document.
- Save metadata on a per-image basis so it can be re-edited.

Examples would be awesome, though links to documentation would also be great. I've found a lot of things, but nothing concrete on how to extract the data as anything but a blob.

Answer (score 0):

(This answer is a work-in-progress. Starting an answer to put the bits as I figure them out. If someone else helps me figure out the missing bits, I'll accept theirs instead of this one).

## How to get the original image URL (or extract it as a base64 string)

As far as I can tell, there isn't a way to get the default URL. I was however able to get the base64 string. It's slightly convoluted, but works.

### Code.gs

```
// Gets an InlineImage in some way. I'm using the currently selected image,  
// but that's irrelevant to the code sample.
// @return {InlineImage}
function getImage() {
    // gets the InlineImage element somehow
}

// Gets the actual data URI.
// Note: this function uses image/png only. You can change this by changing
// it in the two places, or using a variable. Just be sure the two spots 
// match.
// @return {string}
function getDataUri() {
    return 'data:image/png;base64,' + Utilities.base64Encode(getImage().getAs('image/png').getBytes());
}
```

### MyDialogJavaScript.html

```
$(function () {
    google.script.run
   .withSuccessHandler(function (data) { console.log(data); })
   .withFailureHandler(function (err) { console.log('failure: ' + err); })
   .getDataUri();
});
```

An important note: you must SandboxMode.IFRAME when creating the dialog or else you'll get something like:

```
Rejecting <img>.setAttribute('src', blahblahblah
```

This is apparently due to a limitation in the Caja compiler normally used. See the answer here for more info: [Using base64-encoded images with HtmlService in Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20656803/using-base64-encoded-images-with-htmlservice-in-apps-script)