# Get Image From Google Drive for Script-Based Web Page

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to get a png image in google drive to appear on a google apps script html page. I can get the image to appear on the script html page if it is just at a URL somewhere on the web (see commented out line below), but not from google drive. Here is part of the code where I am trying to get as a blob and then use it in an image tag:

```
function getImage() {
//The next 2 lines don't produce the image on the page
  var image = DriveApp.getFileById('File Id Goes Here').getBlob().getAs('image/png');
  var image = '<img src = "' + image + '" width = "90%">'
  //Note, the next line uncommented produces an image on the page
//var image = '<img src = "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" width = "90%">'
return image
}

function doGet() {
  var htmlToAppend = getImage(); 
   var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate()
              .setTitle('Google Image').append(htmlToAppend).setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);  
  return html;    
}
```

The result is a missing image on the html page produced by the script, with the URL for the missing image ending in script.googleusercontent.com/Blob

Info on Blob is here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob (open in a separate page/tab)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you can see the [Using base64-encoded images with HtmlService in Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30739632/5995040) or [Displaying files (e.g. images) stored in Google Drive on a website](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11855448/5995040), there are some workaround to get the image from drive.

One workaround is using the [`IFRAME` sandbox mode](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/sandbox-mode), but this doesn't support old browsers.

All that's required is to call setSandboxMode() on your template, and your data URIs should work as expected:

```
var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(
'<img src="data:' + contentType + ';base64,' + encoded + '"/>'
);

output.setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
```

The second is using the permalink of the file:

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id={fileId}
```

But be noted that [Serving images in an Apps Script through HtmlService](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2015/08/deprecating-web-hosting-support-in.html) is deprecated .

```
<img src="https://googledrive.com/host/0B12wKjuEcjeiySkhPUTBsbW5j387M/my_image.png" height="95%" width="95%">
```

Also, refrain from using same variable names to avoid error from occuring

Hope this helps.