# Google Script sidebar images

Tags: google-apps-script

I am creating a google add-on toolbar with google script. The point of the app is for users to click on some pre-set images in the sidebar that will add them to the google doc. Is there any way to add images to the project folder?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "the project folder"? Is this related to the use of relative path in HTML?

Comment: may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20656803/using-base64-encoded-images-with-htmlservice-in-apps-script

Answer (score 3):

You can host image urls in your drive and link them using [webContent](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource) link: `<img src="[DRIVE webContent Link]">`.

Alternatively, If the images are small, You can directly save the [`dataURIs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) in project folder.